# ReactJS: How to access and update nested state object with dynamic key?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Suppose I have a component with state defined as follows:

```
this.state = {
    apple:{
        a:1,
        b:2,
    },
    mango:{
        banana : {
            a:1,
            b:2,
        }
    }
}
```

If I wanted to update the value of a nested object in my state, I could do so with hard coded keys as shown below:

```
cost temp =  { ...this.state['mango'] }
temp['banana']['a'] = 2;

this.setState({mango:temp});
```

How would I update a nested value in my state object dynamically key? For example, if I had a JSON path in either dot or array notation, how could I update my component state?

Comment: How would the inputs be provided so that you can access these keys dynamically?

Comment: either with dot notation or array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to acquire the nested object that is the parent of the field that your path is targeting via `Array#reduce`:

```
const nestedObject = path
.slice(0, -1)
.reduce((object, part) => (object === undefined ? undefined : object[part]), { ...state })
```

And then update the last key/value of `nestedObject` by via the last key of your path:

```
/* Get last part of path, and update nestedObject's value for this key, to 2 */
const [pathTail] = path.slice(-1);    
nestedObject[pathTail] = 2;
```

The following snippet shows these two ideas together:

```js
/* Path of nested field to update, in array notation */
const path = ['mango', 'banana', 'a'];

/* Components state */
const state = {
  apple: {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
  },
  mango: {
    banana: {
      a: 1,
      b: 2,
    }
  }
};

const stateClone = { ...state };

/* Aquire the parent object (ie banana) of the target field (ie a) */
const nestedObject = path
.slice(0, -1)
.reduce((object, part) => (object === undefined ? undefined : object[part]), stateClone)

if (nestedObject !== undefined) {

  /* Obtain last key in path */
  const [pathTail] = path.slice(-1);

  /* Update value of last key on target object to new value */
  nestedObject[pathTail] = 2;
}

/* Display updated state */
console.log('Updated state:', stateClone)

/* Call this.setState: */
// this.setState(stateClone);
```

#### Update

Here is some extra detail outlining how the `reduce()` part of the answer works:

```
path
/* slice obtains ['mango', 'banana'], seeing -1 clips last item */
.slice(0, -1)  
/* reduce iterates through each part of array ['mango', 'banana']
where at each iteration we fetch the corresponding nested object 
of the { ...state } object that's passed in */
.reduce((object, part) => {

/* At iteration 1: 
object has two keys, 'apple' and 'mango'
part is 'mango'
object is defined, so return object['mango'] for first iteration

At iteration 2:
object passed from last iteration has one key, 'banana'
part is 'banana'
object is defined, so return object['banana'] for second iteration

Reduce complete:
we return object['banana'], which is the same as state['mango']['banana']
*/

if(object === undefined) { return undefined; }

return object[part]

}, stateClone)
```

Comment: You are awesome brother and can you give me one more favor please explain reduce function in your example

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help! Sure, I'll update my answer with a bit more detail :-)

Comment: it works fine but change in state doesn't reflect until i set state even for any other variable

Comment: Yes, you will need to pass the `stateClone` object above to `setState()` to cause the component to update based on the new state

Comment: yes now it's working fine with state clone its speed also increase

Comment: Next Level!  I used this in my hangleChange and solved my 'this' problems.

Answer (score 0):

Having:

```
 const [formState, setFormState] = useState(
      {
        id:1,
        name:'Name',
        innerObjectName: {
            propA: 'Something',
            propB: 'Another thing',
        }
      });
```

Maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
   const handleComplexInputChange = (evt, object) => {
      setFormState({
         ...formState,
         [object] : {
            ...formState[object],
            [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value,
         }
      })
   }
```

And from your component you should call it like this:

```
   onChange={(e) => {
        handleComplexInputChange(e, "innerObjectName");
   }}
```